# Invoke method from different classes that was implemented from an Interface

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, simple-injector

I have an interface that is being inherited by two classes and implements its method Validate (No issues here).

```
public interface IValidator
{
   IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(MyModel model);
}

public class ValidatorA : IValidator
{
   public IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(MyModel model)
   {
       var list = new List<ValidationError>();

       //code to add items to list

       return list;
   }
}

public class ValidatorB : IValidator
{
   public IEnumerable<ValidationError> Validate(MyModel model)
   {
       var list = new List<ValidationError>();

       //code to add items to list

       return list;
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to call the method from the interface and invoke all method from the class (ValidatorA, ValidatorB) that inherits the interface.  Below is how I do it but it doesn't hit the child classes.  What am I doing wrong or what is the proper way to do it?

```
//assuming this is inside a method of another class
//and injected inside
var validationErrors = _myInterfaceValidator.SelectMany(x => x.Validate(myModel));  //why is this not hitting validate from the child classes
return validationErrors.ToList();
```

Okay probably some people on the comment sections are correct that the issue could not be here.
So I'm guessing it's from the SimpleInjector, because I registered the interface like the one below:

```
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IValidator));
```

Could this be the issue?

Comment: That should work. Are you getting errors? If you put a breakpoint in your `Validate` methods, they aren't getting hit?

Comment: no errors... yeah when I try to put breakpoint on the validate of child classes it doesn't hit.

Comment: Typo `=> public interface ValidatorB : IValidator`?

Comment: ValidatorB should be class, not interface

Comment: Beside the typo in your example code, your query definitely behaves as you expected it. Put a break point into each Validate() method and run the debugger.

Comment: Otherwise you did a mistake in a place you didn't show e.g. setting up the test. Post a working example that shows how you are testing it.

Comment: please tell me when you updated your code

Comment: @BionicCode as i said i already placed a breakpoint in each but it doesn't hit.. there's no error.. the app is running it's just not hitting the method

Comment: What's `_myInterfaceValidator`? how is it populated?

Comment: I updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you guys are correct, the issue is the way I register the service to my simple injector.

This is how it should be:

```
var myValidators = new List<Type>(){ typeof(ValidatorA), typeof(ValidatorB) };
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IValidator), myValidators);
```

Just for brief explanation.

The reason that there's no error, is that the app recognizes my IValidator when I registered it.  And the reason why it doesn't invoke the Validate methods from the classes that implements the interface is that, those classes weren't registered as child classes in the SimpleInjector.  Hence will not show any error since the only required for registering to SimpleInjector are parent classes (Interface in this context).